# Add war file to java.class.path in JBoss environment

Tags: java, jboss, classpath

I'm using a library that scans my classpath in order to find the implementation for my interface (this might seem strange and I know there are better approaches but I cannot change this). 
When I'm using this library in a standalone application it works since

```
java.class.path
```

returns the classpath my jar file is on. Now I'm trying to use this library in a web project deployed to a Jboss 7. When asking the classpath in this case this is returned:

```
java.class.path /Applications/jboss-as-7.1.1.Final/jboss-modules.jar
```

I do not really know how I can add something to the java.class.path env variable. Any ideas how i can add something to this variable or a better approach towards this problem?
An add() function exists in this lib where I can add a jar file that needs to be scanned. So if someone can tell me how I can get the location of this war file, that would help as well ;).

This is the library I'm talking about: 
http://software.clapper.org/javautil/

Note: the java.class.path is used inside this library and i do not really want to change anything to said lib.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you looked in run.sh or run.bat for your JBoss server? Does it set a classpath variable in that file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no portable way to do classpath scanning without being able to control the class loader. Better options to achieve this are:

- use [ServiceLoader](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ServiceLoader.html) and `META-INF/services`
- use CDI and register the implementations as CDI beans

Comment: Thanks, you did not solve my problem but you fixed my setup. What I was doing was implementing something like the ServiceLoader myself. I did not know what the ServiceLoader was, I've never heard of it. I've looked into it and it is exactly what i need and is embedded in java itself.
Now i can use the serviceloader to find the implementation (which i can specifiy in de META-INF/service) and create an instance of my interface.